# parsing nodejs from inside of a nodejs script

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

is it possible to parse a node js file and run part of the code from inside of another node js file?

I have a node.js file that I am trying to parse from inside another node.js script. I don't control the contents of the file, but it is valid node.js and it always has a function inside of the code called:
getParameterDefinitions

Here is a file I am trying to parse:
https://github.com/jscad/OpenJSCAD.org/blob/master/examples/gear.jscad

Specifically I want the JSON array returned from getParameterDefinitions as a variable in my code.

Here is the code I have currently:

```
const fs = require('fs')
inputFile = 'gear.jscad'
let src = fs.readFileSync(inputFile, 'UTF8')
console.log(src)
params = Parse(src,'getParameterDefinitions') //how to write this line?
```

How can I have node parse the javascript and run the function to get me back the results into the params variable.

Comment: If you think the code is safe, then use `eval`.

Comment: even with eval, how do I call the getParameterDefinitions function?

Comment: `function getValues(code) { eval(code); return getParameterDefinitions(); }`. Then call it like: `var params = getValues(src);`. **BUT** only if you're sure `src` doesn't contain any harmful code.

Comment: Its not `eval(code)` its `evil(code)`. ;) BTW, avoid `eval` at all costs especially in `node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people may suggest using `eval`. But there's a slightly cleaner way: the `Function` constructor - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). Then do this:

```
const getGetParameterDefinitions = new Function(src + ";\nreturn getParameterDefinitions;");
const getParameterDefinitions = getGetParameterDefinitions();
const params = getParameterDefinitions();
```

or else this:

```
const getParameterDefinitions = new Function(src + ";\nreturn getParameterDefinitions();");
const params = getParameterDefinitions();
```

(Note: the argument to `Function` is slightly different in these two cases.)

This is still a bad idea though - don't do it unless you trust the people who wrote the code.

Also, I'm assuming that the function `getParameterDefinitions` is declared in the outermost scope of the `src` script.

Comment: this code doesnt seem to work, it returns this: [Function: getParameterDefinitions]

Comment: Yes, that was the function you needed to call. I've now added that bit on the end of the answer.